# Multiple submeshes not rendered

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, render, mesh

I am developing a basic CAD application in Unity and I am having some issues with submeshes not rendering. I am just doing a cube and I am getting the submeshes in a List<int[]>, but only the first submesh gets rendered. I want to use submeshes because I would like to use different materials on the meshes. What am I missing here?

I tried the code that I saw in other posts and even made sure that the submesh count looks right. When I comment out the first List<int[]> then the second face is rendered, but nothing else. I would like the whole cube to be rendered. It looks like there is an issue with using multiple submeshes.

```
private void CreateMesh()
{
    Mesh mesh = mf.mesh;
    mesh.Clear();

    List<Vector3> vertList = DoVertices();
    mesh.SetVertices(vertList);

    List<int[]> triDex = DoTriangles();
    mesh.subMeshCount = triDex.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < triDex.Count; i++)
    {
        mesh.SetTriangles(triDex[i], i);
    }

    Debug.Log("mesh.subMeshCount = " + mesh.subMeshCount);

    List<Vector2> uvsList = DoUVs_TEST();
    mesh.uv = uvsList.ToArray();

    MeshRenderer mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    mr.material = defaultMaterial;

    mesh.RecalculateNormals();

    ResetCollider(mesh);

    mf.mesh = mesh;
}


private List<Vector3> DoVertices()
{
    List<Vector3> vertList = new List<Vector3>();

    // Face 1
    Vector3 pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 0
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 1
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 2
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 3

    // Face 2
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 4
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 5
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 6
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 7

    // Face 3
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 8
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 9
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 10
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 11

    // Face 4
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 12
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 13
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 14
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 15

    // Face 5
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 16
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 17
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 18
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 19

    // Face 6
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 20
    pt = new Vector3(-widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 21
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, -depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 22
    pt = new Vector3(widthUnit / 2, -lengthUnit / 2, depthUnit / 2);
    vertList.Add(pt);   // 23

    return vertList;
}


private List<int[]> DoTriangles()
{
    List<int[]> tris = new List<int[]>();

    int[] tri1 = new int[12] { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 8, 10, 11 };
    tris.Add(tri1);

    int[] tri2 = new int[6] { 4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7 };
    tris.Add(tri2);

    int[] tri3 = new int[6] { 12, 13, 14, 12, 14, 15 };
    tris.Add(tri3);

    int[] tri4 = new int[6] { 16, 17, 18, 16, 18, 19 };
    tris.Add(tri4);

    int[] tri5 = new int[6] { 20, 21, 22, 20, 22, 23 };
    tris.Add(tri5);

    return tris;
}


protected void ResetCollider(Mesh mesh)
{
    meshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = null;
    meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
}
```

The following did not solve my problem:
[Unity3D only first submeshed is rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189372/unity3d-only-first-submeshed-is-rendered)

Comment: just a general guess: you only assign a single material .. wouldn't you need one for each submesh?